# Add letters over a panel of figures (multiple figures)

Tags: graphics, includegraphics, letters

Given the following panel of figures (multiple figures)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\setlength{\lineskip}{0pt}
\centering

\includegraphics[width=4cm]{snow.jpg}
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{snow.jpg}\\
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{snow.jpg}
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{snow.jpg}

\caption{Some caption}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**How can I add the "a", "b", "c", "d" letters over each of these 4 figures?**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example uses `tikz` and the `tikzmark` library to add the four letters.

*(You don't need to understand tikz code)*

The command `\InsertLabels{<x offset>}{y offset}` will add the bold letters **a**, **b**, **c** and **d** with an x -y offset from the top left corner of each image.

Before using `\InsertLabels`, you shouldn (1) load one image (assuming all four have the same aspect ratio) with the `\settoheight{\imageheight}{...` command to determine the height of the images;  and (2) add all four  `\tikzmark{<unique name>}` before each `\includegraphics` as shown in the code.

Use the command `\FontLabel` set the font of the labels.

Do not confuse the *name* of the marks used here a, b, c, and d with the letter you want to insert into the image, placed inside the command node in braces, i.e. `{c}`.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

%**************************************************** added <<<<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,tikzmark} 
\newlength{\imageheight}
\settoheight{\imageheight}{% measure the image height
    \includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image} % your image <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
}

\newcommand{\FontLabel}{\sffamily\bfseries\large}% set the font of the labels <<<<<<<<

\newcommand{\InsertLabels}[2]{% 
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
        \node[font=\FontLabel] at ( $ (pic cs:a) +(#1,\imageheight-#2) $ ){a};% 
        \node[font=\FontLabel] at ( $ (pic cs:b) +(#1,\imageheight-#2) $ ){b};% 
        \node[font=\FontLabel] at ( $ (pic cs:c) +(#1,\imageheight-#2) $ ){c};% 
        \node[font=\FontLabel] at ( $ (pic cs:d) +(#1,\imageheight-#2) $ ){d};% 
    \end{tikzpicture}   
}
%****************************************************

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{figure}[htp]
        \setlength{\lineskip}{0pt}
        \centering
        
        \tikzmark{a}\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image} % tikzmark added <<<<<<<<
        \tikzmark{b}\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image}\\ % tikzmark added <<<<<<<<
        \tikzmark{c}\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image} % tikzmark added <<<<<<<<
        \tikzmark{d}\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image} % tikzmark added <<<<<<<<
        
        \caption{Some caption}
        
    \end{figure}
    
    \InsertLabels{3ex}{3ex}% \InsertLabels{<x offset>}{y offset}
    
\end{document}
```

The `tikzmark` library uses the `pic` coordinate system, so the marks are called using `pic cs: mark name`. For example `(pic cs:a)`.

The library `calc` allow the notation `+(< xshift >, < yshift >)` to refer to a point from the origin.

An equivalent result can be obtained using just `tikz` with two nodes: one containing the image and another with the bold letter placed inside the image and using the top left corner of the image as a reference.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{tikz}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}
    
\begin{figure}[htp]
    \setlength{\lineskip}{0pt}
    \centering
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0){\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image}};
        \node[font=\sffamily\bfseries\large] at (3ex,-3ex) {a};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0){\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image}};
        \node[font=\sffamily\bfseries\large] at (3ex,-3ex) {b};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0){\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image}};
        \node[font=\sffamily\bfseries\large] at (3ex,-3ex) {c};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0){\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image}};
        \node[font=\sffamily\bfseries\large] at (3ex,-3ex) {d};
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \caption{Some caption}
\end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great @Simon Dispa!! It works very well! :-)